# How to encrypt a website cookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have read about users being able to manipulate website cookie and use it to exploits security loopholes. I did a search and came across an idea posted online. Here is the code below that is, after the username and password of the user are authenticated;

```
$Separator = '--';
$uniqueID = 'jhlhgjh12u0@345';
$Data = $userID.' '.md5('65748');

$expire=time()+60*24;
setcookie('verify-user', $Data.$Separator.md5($Data.$uniqueID), $expire);
```

The code above will set the cookie using a uniqueID, the userID, a MD5 hash numbers and a separator. The uniqueID, md5 hash numbers and separator are set by the developer. The idea is that a user won't be able to manipulate the cookie because the don't know the UniqueID, and the md5 hash numbers. The code below is used to test each cookie if they are manipulated or not

```
if ($_COOKIE) {

$Separator="--";
$uniqueID = 'jhlhgjh12u0@345';

$Cut = explode($Separator, $_COOKIE['verify-user']);
if (md5($Cut[0].$uniqueID) === $Cut[1]) {
   $_COOKIE['verify-user'] = $Cut[0];

 } else {

   echo "fake cookie";

}
}
else {
   echo "fake cookie";
}
```

I am wondering if this method is security tight or if there are loopholes too. criticism and corrections are welcomed

Comment: md5 is **unsafe** to use for any type of security

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, a completely random cookie with all associated information stored server-side should be preferred.

Comment: @Thilo: which is already implemented for you in PHP, by using sessions.

Comment: Why doing such things? Remember, your session cookie is only a _key_ to session data. Use `session.http_only` flag to prevent most of XSS attacks

Comment: Assume userID refer to a user which is constant, $Data.$Separator.md5($Data.$uniqueID) is a constant as well. If I have a copy of this value I can fake that logged in user session (if nothing else is done).

Comment: @KenCheung I thought of that too, that is why am asking.

Comment: @Ken Or basically you're saying that *if I have the cookie, I have the cookie*. Yes indeed, cookie hijacking is a bigger concern here, since the cookies don't expire.

Comment: @deceze cookies don't expire? they do

Comment: @user Cookies don't always automagically expire. They can stay forever if you make them. But that's irrelevant. The *value* of this cookie never expires. Every time you set this cookie, it's the same value. I could come back in 2 years and regardless of whether the cookie has expired or not, if I send this value to your server it will still be valid.

Comment: @deceze I get you now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as *message signing*. You hash the message together with a secret and attach that "signature" to the message itself. This allows the recipient to verify that the creator/signer of the message is in possession of the secret, without revealing the secret itself.

The problem with your particular implementation is that

- the secret is too small
- the hashing algorithm is unsuitable for the task
- the cookies never change and never expire; if a cookie is stolen there's no recourse

You should use a longer secret, the longer the better. You should also use a hashing algorithm that is suited for the task, namely something like HMAC ([hash-based message authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)). E.g.:

```
hash_hmac('sha512', $data, $secret)
```

You can see an implementation of a similar thing, including *expiration of values*, [here](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP/).

---

The most important thing though: think thrice about whether a signed plain text message is the best way to go here in the first place. Perhaps you want a session-like system, in which an entirely meaningless random string is used as an id for data that is stored on the server. This completely eliminates the problem of users manipulating the cookie.