# Encrypting a date / time and also creating a token

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, md5, sha1

so i have been working on a remember me function for my site.

It currently works, but i have been using basic data and not encrypting as i wanted to know exactly what was happening whilst learning.

I am using a cookie and then a db which stores the same data and then the check is made. A new cookie / db entry is made on logging in each time.

So currently this would be the cookie: (the row for the id is a userid, this cookie is set in the login process)

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 $token = '1';
 $cookiedate = date('d-m-y h:i:s a', time());
 $cookie_val = $row['id'] . ':' . $token . ':' . $cookiedate;

 setcookie (
"cookie", 
$cookie_val, 
time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),
'/'
 );
```

What would be my next step from here in terms of some encpytion? Also im not quite sure about the token, should it be a random hash of chars just used as an extra security method?

the website isnt going to be massive, and from logging into someones account you wont be able to cause any damage really as sensitive pages are password promt protected.

Comment: You can create tow cookies
cookie A: what you need inside
cookie B: for ex. sha1(md5(what you need))

Then on read, you check if the values match. It will avoid the user to be able to change values in the cookie A

Comment: Why are you storing the date inside the cookie? Why is that important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An improvement on what you have would be:

1. Generate a random token of, say, 20 characters, e.g.:

   ```
   bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10));
   ```
2. Store that token together with the user identifier (and other relevant data) in your database.
3. Write the token value inside a cookie.

This prevents a few issues:

1. The token data is only known on the server side, the client only gets the key.
2. A user can revoke 'remember me' tokens to prevent future unauthorized access.
3. Tampering with the cookie value will result in an unknown token value, so access will be rejected.

Upon a successful login you would generate a new token.

Generally, to avoid data tampering, you can use [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/hash_hmac) to hash a particular value using a secret key.

Comment: i was extracting the values from the cookie and then logging in the user with them details. Are you saying it would be better to just store a token, and then have in the DB: userid, date+time, token. Then extract the token from the cookie, check it against a match and then pull the details of the match from the db to login the user?

Comment: @user2921557 That's right. Once logged in, you generate a new token.

Comment: okay i see. would work out better in the long run, simpler. Shouldnt take much modification to my current code. hash_hmac() looks interesting too. Cant get my head around it currently but ill have a good read up. Many thanks! Its great to learn better ways of doing things

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply hash your cookie using md5().

Comment: md5 is **NOT** encryption. It's a hash.

Comment: i would hash these as it would be a quick way around it, but i wont learn anything. It may not end up a massive website but for me, getting the security, secure will only help and teach me in the process.

Comment: There is a very good answer here, How to encrypt a website cookie, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398101/how-to-encrypt-a-website-cookie